# Scroll is not working inside a tab control in android app made with Genexus

Tags: android, genexus, genexus-sd

I'm working in an app for android using Genexus Ev3 U2 for smart devices. I have a transaction where I have a tab control with several attributes inside each tab page. One of the tab pages has several combo box attributes and the list is bigger than the screen size; when I test in the android emulator the scroll works fine with the tab in edit and view mode; but when I test on the device (Android 4.1.2) the scroll works in view mode, but no in edit mode.

How could I solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: Tried to reproduce your behaviour but couldn't. Please contact GeneXus' support team adding a sample xpz. www.gxtechnical.com/assistedsupport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems is that the problem was with the Android version (4.1.2). the app generated with Genexus had this problem whit this version, but I tried the app in an Android 4.2.2 and there was no problem with the scrolls inside tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem where the virtual keyboard was hiding EditTexts on my screen. I introduced the following property for activity tag in the manifest file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

Also I needed to add following code in the activity's OnCreate function:

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

This solved the problem and it worked perfectly fine on all resolution emulators and samsung devices. It did fail, though, on Google Nexus S device and I could see the same problem again of virtual keyboard hiding the EditTexts.